# Check Ansible version from inside of a playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that is running in different way in Ansible 1.9.x and 2.0. I would like to check currently running ansible version in my playbook to avoid someone running it with old one.

I don't think that this is the best solution:

```
- local_action: command ansible --version
  register: version
```

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ansible provides a global dict called ansible_version, dict contains the following

```
"ansible_version": {
        "full": "2.7.4", 
        "major": 2, 
        "minor": 7, 
        "revision": 4, 
        "string": "2.7.4"
    }
```

you can use any of the following ansible_version.full, ansible_version.major or any other combination in creating conditional statements to check the version of ansible that's installed.

example playbook: using this dict and a when statement.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Print message if ansible version is greater than 2.7.0
      debug:
        msg: "Ansible version is  {{ ansible_version.full }}"
      when: ansible_version.full >= "2.7.4"
```

Comment: Ansible has [version comparison](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison) built in, so the most stable check to check the ansible version is `ansible_version.full is version('2.7.4', '>=')`

Comment: With using the major, minor and revision field, the type must be integer (instead of string) inside the test statement (e.g. `when: ansible_version.major >= 2`). This does not apply, when using the `is version()` method.

Comment: This does not work. When installed version is "2.14.3" and checking against "2.3.3" it fails. @stavmeir 's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [assert module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html):

```
- assert:
    that: ansible_version.major < 2
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to compare ansible version inside a playbook looks like

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: foo
      when: "ansible_version.full is version_compare('2.11', '>=')"
      ...
```

Do not use string comparison or you will be surprised that it does not work as expected.

Comment: Found that `version_compare` has been renamed; recommends to use `compare` https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions